# Xamarin studio NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, помогите решить проблему. Вылетает ошибка:

> System.NullReferenceException

тогда когда вызываю `Navigation.PushPopupAsync(InfoEntrant);` по которой обращается к окну `PopupPage`.

В чем может быть причина не понимаю?
Так как есть аналогичный проект на VS2015 и все работает отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если попробовать в [Visual Studio для маков](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/)?

Comment: Вы предлагаете установить недавно вышедшую VS для Mac и перенести проект туда, я правильно понял?
Как возможность можно попробовать.

Comment: Собственно, неясно, связанна ли проблема с XS, или в системе чего-то не хватает. Установка VS внесёт ясность. Хотя это, конечно, очень грубый и длинный способ внести ясность, но мало ли, вдруг другого не найдётся

Comment: Можно чуть по подробнее чего может не хватать системе?.
Могу с уверенностью написать что XS стоит последнее обновление.

Comment: К сожалению такая же проблема для VS Mac

Comment: можно строку 88 полностью увидеть?
InfoEntrant где в другом месте определен? какого типа эта переменная/класс?

Comment: Разве перед Navigation.PushPopAsync не должно стоять await?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что речь идёт о мобильном приложении, разрабатываемом в Xamarin (я имею в виду фреймворк. а не редактор). В этом случае есть вероятность, что установлено не всё. Xcode установлен?

Comment: Вот строка 88 `InfoEntrant = new InfoBudgetEntrantBranchBeloretsk();` `private InfoBudgetEntrantBranchBeloretsk InfoEntrant;`. InfoEntrant - это переменная. Совершенно верно у меня уже стоит await, я подправил спасибо замечание.

Comment: eastwing Xcode установлен работаю на операционной системе Mac OS так что я использую Xamarin Studio, а не плагин в Visual Studio.

Comment: WinnerIT.  В await Navigation.PushPopAsync(InfoEntrant) при следующем окне должно отобразить не ContentPage, а PopupPage по которой работаю библиотекой NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/